# Building a Pivot Table in SQL: Aggregation Sorting

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am working on building a pivot table in SQL (mysql), and I'd like to go through this step by step, so this question will be part in a series in trying to build a more and more complex pivot table in SQL.

I have the following schema giving titles:

- provider
- title
- revenue

I would like to build an aggregation that groups by Provider and Title, like so:

```
provider    title      revenue
Sony        titanic    9.99
Paramount   T2         14.99
Sony        star wars  12.99
```

This is straightforward, and we can aggregate it by:

```
SELECT provider, title, SUM(revenue) FROM table GROUP BY provider, title
```

The next thing I'd like to do is sort the Provider first, by the sum of revenue for that provider, and then by the title, alphabetically. For example, the above should be sorted as:

```
[-] Sony (12.99+9.99 = 22.98)
    - star wars (A-Z)
    - titanic (A-Z)
[-] Paramount (9.99)
    - T2
```

How would I do this sort in the aggregation in SQL? Here is a sql fiddle with sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9b5d9/2.

Comment: Why is this tagged with SQL Server and BigQuery if you are using MySQL?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I would assume the same SQL would apply (and it wouldn't be a vendor-specific query). I thought using all the tags would show the query is applicable to any main sql database, but correct me if that's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT b.provider,a.title,b.ttl,sum(a.revenue) AS rev
FROM tab AS a
JOIN (
  SELECT provider,sum(revenue) AS ttl FROM tab GROUP BY 1
) AS b ON a.provider = b.provider
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 3 DESC,2
```

[image]

Cannot open your SQLfiddle, and I copied your SQL into my local site and the result is as per following:

[image]

Comment: take a look at the SQLFiddle data example. The above doesn't seem to sort it properly.

Comment: SQLFiddle not working, but when I copy your SQLs into my local machine, works as expected

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a [with rollup](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) clause for your query:

```
select provider, title, sum(customer_price) revenue from `100`
group by provider, title
with rollup
```

The 'total' rows will have the NULLs in the provider and title columns (and the last row is the Grand Total row), like this:

```
|               provider |                      title | revenue |
|------------------------|----------------------------|---------|
|             DISTRIBBER |                Finding Joe |   16.99 |
|             DISTRIBBER |                     (null) |   16.99 |
|            Echo Bridge |               Do Something |    1.99 |
|            Echo Bridge |                 Down in LA |       0 |
|            Echo Bridge | The L.A. Complex, Season 1 |   19.99 |
|            Echo Bridge | The Other Side of the Door |    6.97 |
|            Echo Bridge |               Who You Know |    3.98 |
|            Echo Bridge |                     (null) |   32.93 |
| Electric Entertainment |         Leverage, Season 4 |   31.99 |
| Electric Entertainment |     The Cross My Heart Job |    2.99 |
| Electric Entertainment |             The Inside Job |    1.99 |
| Electric Entertainment |              The Radio Job |    1.99 |
| Electric Entertainment |       The Scheherazade Job |    2.99 |
| Electric Entertainment |                     (null) |   41.95 |
|               HALLMARK |      The Good Witch's Gift |    3.99 |
|               HALLMARK |                     (null) |    3.99 |
|            Quebec Inc. |        2 Frogs In the West |    5.99 |
|            Quebec Inc. |                     (null) |    5.99 |
|                 VIRGIL |         One Lucky Elephant |    3.99 |
|                 VIRGIL |                     (null) |    3.99 |
|                 (null) |                     (null) |  105.84 |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2baff/1)

Comment: this doesn't appear to be sorting by the provider revenue desc though?

Comment: I will leave it as an exercise for you